# Why can't I exclude 2 or more patterns from the find command in Linux?

Tags: linux, find

I am attempting to exclude `.svg` and `.jpg` files from my find command however it still returns both of them. What am I doing wrong?

```
find . \( ! -iname \*\.svg -o ! -iname \*\.jpg \)
```

Comment: Careful, bash (and other) shells use '!' for repeating old commands. Some bash versions don't even allow to quote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed: With the command you have right now, you find every non-`.svg` or every non-`.jpg` file. What you wrote reads as:

> find (everything that's not an SVG *or* everything that's not a JPG)

So you'll get the JPG files, because `find` already evaluated the first part and gave you everything that's not an SVG file. Because of the way the options are parsed, if the first part of an `or` expression evaluates to true, the second part is not even looked at.

In essence, once `find` returns you everything that's not an SVG, it doesn't care about what you want with the JPG files.

---

The correct way to phrase this would be with a logical `and`:

```
find . \( ! -iname '*.svg' -a ! -iname '*.jpg' \)
```

This reads as:

> find (everything that's not an SVG *and* everything that's not a JPG)

Or, by negating the whole expression:

```
find . ! \(-iname '*.svg' -o -iname '*.jpg' \)
```

Which reads as:

> find everything that's not (an SVG *or* a JPG)

<sub>Note that you can skip escaping the `*` if you simply put it in single or double quotes, e.g. `-iname '*.jpg'`. This is much easier to read.</sub>

Comment: Awesome. I was using `-o` blindly not knowing it stood for `OR`. Now I know.